# comunication between pages in php

Tags: php, forms

HI,

I wrote this code in php.

```
    <head>
<title>listent</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="untitled 3.php">
<input type = "text" name = "user">
<br>
<textarea name = "address" rows = "10" cols = "40">

</textarea>
<br>
<input type = "submit" value = "heat it">
<br>
<select name="combobox" multiple[]>
<option>mehdi
<option>nine
</select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

now when i click on submit button `untitled 3.php` is run.

in untitled 3.php i wrote

```
<?php

print "welcome $user";



?>
```

but it has error.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\me\Untitled 3.php on line 4
welcome
```

what is problem?how can i solve it?

Comment: do you **really** have a space in the filename "untitled 3.php"?

Comment: See [That's because ("global") variables aren't really global in PHP.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form values don't just magically appear as variables anymore - at least not in any decently modern and properly configured PHP installation. You need to do `$_GET["user"]` to access the value which is sent by the form (into the URL - you might want to read about the difference between GET and POST)

And please, *please* use more descriptive names for your files...

Answer (score 1):

PHP Globals wont survive the new page.

In you case you must use the POST variables sent by your form.

So in untitled3.php you should have

```
echo "welcome ".$_POST['user'];
```

PS : I would avoid spaces in PHP filenames.

Comment: The form isn't going to send POST data, it doesn't have a method attribute.

Answer (score 1):

First you should specify a [Form submission method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1) in your first page:

```
<form  action="untitled 3.php" method="post">
```

Then you have access to all posted values in the `$_POST` array in `untitled 3.php`:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

Comment: The method attribute is explicitly optional.

Comment: it didn't have any error but in page showed  **Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\me\Untitled 3.php on line 4**

Comment: @David Dorward Thanks, I didn't know that, I've never omitted it.

Comment: @mehdi If you haven't added a method, it seems you can use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. You can also use `$_REQUEST` as that is both arrays combined, but I personally prefer to specify a method and get the values accordingly.